Error running WSGI application. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_auto_logout'
I'm trying to deploy my Django project via project using pythonanywhere but I have a problem and I'm really stuck. Can anyone help me with this. The image attached to the path toenter image description here my settings.py file
enter image description here
enter image description here
And The Error shows after I reload is:
enter image description here
What should I do?
Thanks in advance.
Locally on my computer, the application functions correctly. But when I deploy it in Pythonanywhere I get an error on the Django logout module.
I can't resolve this problem.

Have you installed django_auto_logout?  If you're using a virtualenv, you'll need to install it into that env, and if you're not you'll just have to install it at a global level.  This PythonAnywhere help page has instructions.

Run pip list in your environment to see all the installed packages. If django-auto-logout is missing, then you have to install it just as Giles Thomas mentioned in the comments. To install django-auto-logout, run
pip install django-auto-logout

and add the following to your settings middlewares:
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    'django_auto_logout.middleware.auto_logout',
]

Note
Make sure that the following middlewares are used before doing this:
django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware

django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware

django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware

See https://pypi.org/project/django-auto-logout/
